# setq and defvar in Lisp

Tags: variables, lisp, common-lisp, assign, variable-declaration

I see that the [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) uses `(defvar *db* nil)` for setting up a *global variable*. Isn't it OK to use `setq` for the same purpose?

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using `defvar` vs. `setq`?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**There are several ways to introduce variables.**

[DEFVAR](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm#defvar) and [DEFPARAMETER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm#defparameter) introduce *global* dynamic variables. `DEFVAR` optionally sets it to some value, unless it is already defined. `DEFPARAMETER` sets it always to the provided value.
[SETQ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm#setq) does not introduce a variable.

```
(defparameter *number-of-processes* 10)

(defvar *world* (make-world))     ; the world is made only once.
```

Notice that you likely never want to `DEFVAR` variables with names like `x`, `y`, `stream`, `limit`, ... Why? Because these variables then would be declared special and its difficult to undo that. The special declaration is global and all further uses of the variable would use dynamic binding.

BAD:

```
(defvar x 10)     ; global special variable X, naming convention violated
(defvar y 20)     ; global special variable Y, naming convention violated

(defun foo ()
  (+ x y))        ; refers to special variables X and y

(defun bar (x y)  ; OOPS!! X and Y are special variables
                  ; even though they are parameters of a function!
  (+ (foo) x y))

(bar 5 7)         ; ->   24
```

BETTER: Always mark special variables with `*` in their names!

```
(defvar *x* 10)     ; global special variable *X*
(defvar *y* 20)     ; global special variable *Y*

(defun foo ()
  (+ *x* *y*))      ; refers to special variables X and y

(defun bar (x y)    ; Yep! X and Y are lexical variables
  (+ (foo) x y))

(bar 5 7)           ;  ->   42
```

**Local variables are introduced with [DEFUN](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defun.htm#defun), [LAMBDA](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/a_lambda.htm#lambda), [LET](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_let_l.htm#let), [MULTIPLE-VALUE-BIND](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_multip.htm#multiple-value-bind) and many others.**

```
(defun foo (i-am-a-local-variable)
   (print i-am-a-local-variable))

(let ((i-am-also-a-local-variable 'hehe))
  (print i-am-also-a-local-variable))
```

Now, by default the local variables in above two forms are lexical, unless they are declared *SPECIAL*. Then they would be dynamic variables.

**Next, there are also several forms to set a variable to new values.** [SET](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_set.htm#set), [SETQ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm#setq), [SETF](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_setf_.htm) and others. `SETQ` and `SETF` can set both lexical and special (dynamic) variables.

It is required for portable code that one sets variables that are already declared. The exact effect of setting a not declared variable is undefined by the standard.

So, if you know what your Common Lisp implementation does, you can use

```
(setq world (make-new-world))
```

in the *Read-Eval-Print-Loop* at the toplevel. But don't use it in your code, since the effect is not portable. Typically `SETQ` will set the variable. But some implementation might also declare the variable *SPECIAL* when it doesn't know it (CMU Common Lisp does that by default). That's almost always not what one would want. Use it for casual use if you know what you do, but not for code.

Same here:

```
(defun make-shiny-new-world ()
  (setq world (make-world 'shiny)))
```

First, such variables should be written as `*world*`  (with the surrounding `*` characters), to make clear that it is a global special variable. Second, it should have been declared with `DEFVAR` or `DEFPARAMETER` before.

A typical Lisp compiler will complain that above variable is undeclared. Since global lexical variables don't exist in Common Lisp, the compiler has to generate code for a dynamic lookup. Some compiler then say, okay, we assume that this is a dynamic lookup, let's declare it to be *special* - since that is what we assume anyway.

Comment: I'm surprised that once you have declared the variable to be global with defvar, there is no way you can make a local variable with the same name, so (let ((x 1)) x) may produce unexpected results if x is declared by defvar.

Comment: @ian That's one reason why many people use "ear muffs" (that is, they never use `(defvar x foo)`, they use `(defvar *x* foo)`, that way you're much less likely to make a mistake.

Answer (score 24):

`defvar` introduces a dynamic variable while `setq` is used to assign a value to a dynamic or lexical variable. The value of a dynamic variable is looked up in the environment that calls the function, while the value of a lexical variable is looked up in the environment where the function was defined. The following example will make the difference clear:

```
;; dynamic variable sample
> (defvar *x* 100)
*X*
> (defun fx () *x*)
FX
> (fx)
100
> (let ((*x* 500)) (fx)) ;; gets the value of *x* from the dynamic scope.
500
> (fx) ;; *x* now refers to the global binding.
100

;; example of using a lexical variable
> (let ((y 200))
   (let ((fy (lambda () (format t "~a~%" y))))
     (funcall fy) ;; => 200
     (let ((y 500))
       (funcall fy) ;; => 200, the value of lexically bound y
       (setq y 500) ;; => y in the current environment is modified
       (funcall fy)) ;; => 200, the value of lexically bound y, which was 
                     ;; unaffected by setq
     (setq y 500) => ;; value of the original y is modified.
     (funcall fy))) ;; => 500, the new value of y in fy's defining environment.
```

Dynamic variables are useful for passing around a default value. For instance, we can bind the dynamic variable `*out*` to the standard output, so that it becomes the default output of all io functions. To override this behavior, we just introduce a local binding:

```
> (defun my-print (s)
        (format *out* "~a~%" s))
MY-PRINT
> (my-print "hello")
hello
> (let ((*out* some-stream))
    (my-print " cruel ")) ;; goes to some-stream
> (my-print " world.")
world
```

A common use of lexical variables is in defining closures, to emulate objects with state. In the first example, the variable `y` in the binding environment of `fy` effectively became the private state of that function.

`defvar` will assign a value to a variable only if it is not already assigned. So the following re-definition of `*x*` will not change the original binding:

```
> (defvar *x* 400)
*X*
> *x*
100
```

We can assign a new value to `*x*` by using `setq`:

```
> (setq *x* 400)
400
> *x*
400
> (fx)
400
> (let ((*x* 500)) (fx)) ;; setq changed the binding of *x*, but 
                         ;; its dynamic property still remains.
500
> (fx)
400
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is wrong. The exact effect of a (setq y 200) on a not declared/defined variable is undefined. Common Lisp also does not have global lexical variables. SETQ sets a variable. Nothing more. Either a dynamic variable or a lexical variable, depending on the variable provided. LET binds. SETQ sets.

Comment: Also one can't define a function CL:PRINT, since that name is already taken by the standard function. FORMAT prints to streams, not files.

Comment: @Rainer Thanks for pointing out the inaccuracies. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 10):

[DEFVAR](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpar.htm) establishes a new variable.  [SETQ](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_setq.htm) assigns to a variable.

Most Lisp implementations I've used will issue a warning if you SETQ to a variable that doesn't yet exist.

Answer (score 8):

`defvar` and `defparameter` both introduce global variables. As Ken notes, `setq` assigns to a variable.

In addition, `defvar` will not clobber something previously `defvar`-ed. Seibel says later in the book (Chapter 6): "Practically speaking, you should use DEFVAR to define variables that will contain data you'd want to keep even if you made a change to the source code that uses the variable."

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html

For instance, if you have a global `*db*` for the database in the Simple Database chapter:

```
(defvar *db* nil)
```

...and you start playing with it at the REPL - adding, deleting things, etc - but then you make a change to the source file which contains that defvar form, reloading that file will not wipe out `*db*` and all the changes you might have made... I believe that `setq` will, as will `defparameter`. A more experienced Lisper please correct me if I'm wrong though.