# What's difference between defvar, defparameter, setf and setq

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I found a [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855862/setq-and-defvar-in-lisp).

But I don't quite understand that explanation.

So I'm trying to run clisp with the following example:

```
  [1]> (defvar a 5)
  A
  [2]> (+ a 1)
  6
  [3]> (defparameter b 5)
  B
  [4]> (+ b 1)
  6
  [5]> (setf c 5)
  5
  [6]> (+ c 1)
  6
  [7]> (setq d 5)
  5
  [8]> (+ d 1)
  6
  [9]> (let ((a 500)) (+ a 1))
  501
  [10]> (let ((b 500)) (+ b 1))
  501
  [11]> (let ((c 500)) (+ c 1))
  501
  [12]> (let ((d 500)) (+ d 1))
  501
  [13]>
```

What I found is totally the same.

I can't figure out what's different with them?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

`DEFPARAMETER` always assigns a value. So:

```
[1]> (defparameter a 1)
A
[2]> (defparameter a 2)
A
[3]> a
2
```

while `DEFVAR` does it only once, so:

```
[4]> (defvar b 1)
B
[5]> (defvar b 2)
B
[6]> b
1
```

`SETF` is a macro which uses `SETQ` internally, but has more possibilities. In a way it's a more general assignment operator. E.g. with `SETF` you can do:

```
[19]> (defparameter c (list 1 2 3))
[21]> (setf (car c) 42)                                              
42
[22]> c
(42 2 3)
```

but you can't do that with `SETQ`:

```
[23]> (setq (car c) 42)                                              
*** - SETQ: (CAR C) is not a symbol
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead.
ABORT          :R2      Abort main loop
Break 1 [24]> abort
```

Comment: If a variable which I define by defvar,can I change value by defparameter? Is the the correct way to do it? Or only the variable define in defparameter can be changed by defparameter? Thank you~

Comment: The right way is to use DEFVAR and DEFPARAMETER for value initializations in files, use one or the other to declare dynamic variables in the listener and always use SETF to change the value in non-toplevel code. The difference between DEFVAR and DEFPARAMETER then becomes "do I want to reset the value every time I load this file," (use defparamete), "or not?" (use defvar).

Answer (score 32):

Both `defvar` and `defparameter` will declare a variable as a "dynamically scoped variable". In addition, `defparameter` will always set the value of the variable to the value you pass in as the second argument. This is different from `defvar`, it will only set the value of the variable if it previously hasn't been set.

Defining a variable with `setf` or `setq` in the global lexical scope is undefined. Some implementations will create a dynamically scoped variable for you, some will not. You may see diagnostic messages when you do it for the first time.

To understand the difference between lexically-scoped and dynamically-scoped variables, try the following code snippet:

```
* (defvar *a* 1)

*A*
* (let ((*a* 5)) (defun demo-a () *a*))

DEMO-A
* (let ((b 5)) (defun demo-b () b))

DEMO-B
* (let ((*a* 100)) (demo-a))

100
* (let ((b 100)) (demo-b))

5
```

Here we create a dynamically-scoped variable and a function that return the value (defined inside a binding where it has a different value during the function creation, this is not necessary and done only to look similar to the lexical closure over b). We then define a new variable and define a function return its value.

After that, we call both functions, inside closures binding a value to a variable of the same name. In the dynamic scoping case, it is the same variable. In the lexical closure case (b), they merely have the same name, but are not the same variable, since they're defined in two different lexical closures.

As far as the difference between `setf` and `setq`, try to always use `setf` (I cannot think of any example where `(setq blah blahblah)` would work and `(setf blah blahblah)` wouldn't do the same thing).

Comment: Now I know the difference between defvar and defparameter. But when is the case we should use setf or setq? Thank you~

Comment: @sam: use `defvar`, `defparameter`, or `let` to introduce new variables. Use `setf` and `setq` to mutate existing variables. Using them to introduce new variables is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Last example (let ((b 100)) (demo-b)) gives me 100 also, not 5 as shown

Comment: @AndreasRöhler If it does you may have done a toplevel `(setq b...)` earlier, that will cause multiple lisp environments to turn the variable into dynamically-scoped. What happens if you try it in a freshly-started Common Lisp?

Comment: @Vatine Ahh, sorry, was at Emacs Lisp dynamically scoped.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `(demo-a)`, without a `let` surrounding its call, evaluates to the `1`.