# Reassigning a global variable within a function without passing variable name

Tags: binding, lisp, common-lisp

As described in the title I try to solve the following problem:

```
(setq s ())

(defun reassign (val)
  (setq val 10))

(reassign s)

(print s)
-> Output: s = nil
```

I want `reassign` to destructively assign `s = 10`.
Is there an easy way to handle this, without using the variable name `s` within the function & only changing the function? (may Macros be included?) I would be grateful for any advice! :)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/3855862/124319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you guessed correctly. you need a macro.

```
(defmacro reassign (var &optional (val 10)) `(setq ,var ,val))

(defvar s ())   ;; @Svante remarked that setq can be dangerous to create a variable
s ;; NIL
(reassign s)
s ;; 10

;; the `&optional (val 10)` makes the value optional and 10 to the 
;; default value of val if not given.
```

In your example

```
(defun reassign (val) (setq val 10))
```

`val` is the first argument of the special form of `setq`: the `val` in the `setq` doesn't become `s` although you gave it `reassign` for `val`. It stays `val` so that you assign 10 in the functional scope to `val`. You can make this visible by:

```
(setq s ())

(defun reassign (val)
  (print "You gave for `val`:")
  (print val) 
  (setq val 10)
  (print "The form assigned 10 literally to val")
  (print "Proof: Print out val in this scope:")
  (print val))

(reassign s)

;; 
;; "You gave for `val`:" 
;; NIL 
;; "The form assigned 10 literally to val" 
;; "Proof: Print out val in this scope:" 
;; 10 
;; 10

(print val)

*** - SYSTEM::READ-EVAL-PRINT: variable VAL has no value
The following restarts are available:
USE-VALUE      :R1      Input a value to be used instead of VAL.
STORE-VALUE    :R2      Input a new value for VAL.
ABORT          :R3      Abort main loop
;; since val has not been initiated before
```

In addition, the `setq` of the function is executed within the functional scope. That is why outside the function val keeps the old value.

```
(defvar val ()) ;; NIL
(print val)   ;; NIL

(defun reassign (val)
  (print "You gave for `val`:")
  (print val) 
  (setq val 10)
  (print "The form assigned 10 literally to val")
  (print "Proof: Print out val in this scope:")
  (print val))

(reassign 'whatever) ;; inside function val becomes 10
;;
;;"You gave for `val`:" 
;;WHATEVER 
;;"The form assigned 10 literally to val" 
;;"Proof: Print out val in this scope:" 
;;10 ;; val becomes indeed 10 until leaving function 
;;10

;; but retains old value after leaving the function
(print val)
;;
;; NIL
;; NIL
```

The macro in contrast replaces the macro call `(reassign s)` by the form `(setq s 10)`. So when executed, the reassignment takes place within the environment where we defined `(defvar s ())`.
Therefore after the reassignment, `s` keeps the newly assigned value, since it was reassigned in the working environment.

Comment: `Setq` is not the correct operator for _creating_ a variable.  Use `defvar`, `defparameter`, `let`, `multiple-value-bind`, `do` etc.

Comment: Thank you, Svante. I have also to learn a lot - you are my teacher!

Comment: Thank you both :)

Comment: Welcome, Kisslax! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun reassign (val)
  (setq val 10))

(reassign s)
```

When you call `(reassign s)`, the value of `s` is passed down to `reassign`, where it is locally bound to `val`. That would be `nil` in your case, assuming you already declared `s` with [`DEFVAR`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) before setting it to `()` (see [setq and defvar in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3855862/124319)).

Inside `reassign`, the call to [`SETQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_setq.htm) changes the local binding.

#### Global binding

Each symbol can hold a global value.
If you want to change the value cell of a symbol, use the [`SYMBOL-VALUE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_5.htm) accessor:

```
(setf (symbol-value 's) 10)
```

Notice how `s` is quoted. You are not changing the symbol currently bound to `s` (which would be `nil`, a constant variable), but the `s` symbol itself. `(SETF SYMBOL)` is like calling [`SET`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_set.htm#set) directly.

#### Lexical and dynamic binding

If however, you want to modify any kind of *place*, and in particular lexical and dynamic variable bindings, you need to define a macro:

```
(defmacro reassign (place)
  `(setf ,place 10))
```

[`SETF`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_setf_.htm) expands into the code necessary to update a place. You could also give `(gethash key table)` instead of just an unquoted variable, which would then update the content of a table.

In the case of local variables, the code that *calls* `reassign` will eventually expands into a call to the special operator [`SETQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_setq.htm), which knows how to change lexical bindings (it also handles [`SYMBOL-MACROLET`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/s_symbol.htm#symbol-macrolet) bindings).