# Shadow a global variable in elisp

Tags: elisp

First I define a global variable `x`:

```
ELISP> (defvar x (cons 1 3))
x
ELISP> x
(1 . 3)
```

After some operations, I want to shadow `x` and reassign its value to 5:

```
ELISP> (defvar x 5)
x
ELISP> x
(1 . 3)
```

But it still has the original value. How can I shadow a global variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setq and defvar in Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3855862/setq-and-defvar-in-lisp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `defvar` form does not override the value if the variable is already defined. This is so that the user can say `(setq preference value)` in their `.emacs` even before loading the package which declares and uses `preference` using `defvar`.

As suggested above, use `setq` to permanently and unconditionally replace any previous value.

To *temporarily* override a value, use `let`.

```
(let ((preference temp-value))
    ... code which needs to see temp-value ...)
;; previous global value is restored after the let form
```